# How to store data on internal memory on LG Optimus 4X HD

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, storage

After first use of LG optimus 4x HD I set storing of photo and video files on a SD card. Now I want this files to be saved back on internal memory.But I can't find where I did this setting. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do:

1. open the camera app
2. in the upper left you see a "gear" icon. Tapping it opens a drop-down. Do so.
3. scroll a little down. The third-to-last item reads "Storage" (has a SDCard icon). Tap it.
4. in the new overlay, select your wanted storage from "SDcard" or "Internal storage"

Done :)

Comment: Goran, sometimes one cannot find the simple things. This doesn't mean one's stupid :) But if my answer helped you, it would be nice of you to "accept" it (click on the checkmark left to it), so it's easily identifyable by others that your issue has a working solution. Thanks!